# Get count of rows per manager

Tags: sql-server

I've been messing around with this for days. I have tables of Managers, Sites they are assigned to, and Growers that are assigned to those sites.  I need to know how many growers a manager has.  Managers are assinged to sites but not growers so I have to go through this drill to find out how many growers a particular manager has based on the grower assigned to each individual site he has.  A site only has one grower.  I can get the number of growers for a particular manager fairly easily but I want to return a single table containing the number of growers for each manager and I'm stumped.

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @ManagerID     INT
DECLARE @getManagerID  CURSOR 
SET @getManagerID =  CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID
FROM   Managers

     OPEN @getManagerID
     FETCH NEXT
     FROM @getManagerID INTO @ManagerID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(Grower) AS NumGrowers
    FROM   Growers
    WHERE  Growers.ID IN 
    (
       SELECT sitesg.Grower
       FROM   SitesG
       WHERE  SitesG.id IN 
       (
          SELECT SITE
          FROM   ManagerSites
          WHERE  ManagerSites.Manager IN 
          (
             SELECT ID
             FROM Managers
             WHERE ID = @ManagerID
          )
       )
    )

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getManagerID INTO @ManagerID
END
     CLOSE @getManagerID
     DEALLOCATE @getManagerID
```

This gives me a bunch of results that I can probably store in a temporary table but there must be a better way.  Any ideas?

-Joe

Comment: This query does not require a cursor. However, when you do use cursors, please don't use the default options. See this post for more details: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options

Comment: Please how sample data and desired results so people don't waste time solving a long-winded and hard to follow word problem.

Comment: Show, not how. Stupid phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please ditch the cursors and all the nested subqueries. This is exactly what joins are for...

```
SELECT ManagerID = m.ID, NumGrowers = COUNT(DISTINCT g.ID)
  FROM dbo.Managers AS m
  INNER JOIN dbo.ManagerSites AS s
  ON s.Manager = m.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.SitesG AS sg
  ON s.SITE = sg.id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Growers AS g
  ON sg.Grower = g.ID
  GROUP BY m.ID;
```

In fact if all you care about is the `ManagerID` you can simplify this:

```
SELECT ManagerID = s.Manager, NumGrowers = COUNT(DISTINCT g.ID)
  FROM dbo.ManagerSites AS s
  INNER JOIN dbo.SitesG AS sg
  ON s.SITE = sg.id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Growers AS g
  ON sg.Grower = g.ID
  GROUP BY s.Manager;
```

As an aside, it is very confusing to be joining things like `s.Manager = m.ID` and `sg.Grower = g.ID`. Why don't you call things `ManagerID`, `GrowerID` etc. the same thing everywhere they appear in your model? That would certainly make these joins more intuitive.

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon.  What the above gives me are the total sites for each grower:
9 596
12 196
10 798
13 491
11 275
14 737

-Joe

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon.  What the above gives me are the total sites for each grower which I have gotten in a similar way and are:
ManagerID  Sites
9 596

12 196

10 798

13 491
11 275
14 737

I need the number of growers That each of theose sites have.  For instance Manager 9 has 130 growers.

-Joe

Comment: To give a little more information.  A manager can have any number of sites and a grower can have any number of sites.  A manager is assigned to lots of sites so I need to look up every site he has, then take all those sites and look up all the growers they have and toss out the duplicates.  -Joe

Comment: That did it.  You are most helpful.  I knew it had to be something simple.  I should have asked someone sooner.  Thanks loads. - Joe

Comment: Oops, forgot about that.  I think I have it checked now. -Joe

Comment: I have updated.  I would have right away but I've been a little bleary-eyed lately. -Joe